# A slight confusion about a particular step in Euclidean Transformations (Computer Vision)

Tags: machine-learning, rigid-transformation

On page 392 of Computer vision by Simon Prince (http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/s.prince/book/book.pdf), equation 15.2 has the following expression for the Euclidean transformation in homogeneous coordinates:

$$
\lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\1
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_x&\gamma&\delta_x\\
0 &\phi_y&\delta_y\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{11}&w_{12}&\tau_x\\
w_{21}&w_{22}&\tau_y\\
0&0&D
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} u\\v\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

In what follows, he switches the position of $1$ and $D$:

$$
\lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\1
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_x&\gamma&\delta_x\\
0 &\phi_y&\delta_y\\
0&0&D
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{11}&w_{12}&\tau_x\\
w_{21}&w_{22}&\tau_y\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} u\\v\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

with the comment that the last equation is unchanged.

My question is this: the other two equations do seem to change when you make this switch, so firstly, why can we make this switch? Secondly, is there a geometric explanation underlying this switch?

Edit:

Here are the multiplied out matrices:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_x&\gamma&\delta_x\\
0 &\phi_y&\delta_y\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{11}&w_{12}&\tau_x\\
w_{21}&w_{22}&\tau_y\\
0&0&D
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_x w_{11} + \gamma w_{21}&\phi_x w_{12} + \gamma w_{22}&\phi_x \tau_x + \gamma \tau_y + D\delta_x\\
\phi_y w_{21}& \phi_y w_{22}&\phi_y \tau_y + D\delta_y\\
0&0&D
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_x&\gamma&\delta_x\\
0 &\phi_y&\delta_y\\
0&0&D
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{11}&w_{12}&\tau_x\\
w_{21}&w_{22}&\tau_y\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_x w_{11} + \gamma w_{21}&\phi_x w_{12} + \gamma w_{22}&\phi_x \tau_x + \gamma \tau_y + \delta_x\\
\phi_y w_{21}& \phi_y w_{22}&\phi_y \tau_y + \delta_y\\
0&0&D
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

As can be seen in the last column, the first two equations have changed.

Edit 2:

I have checked with my lecturer and he thinks that there might be an error in the book.

Comment: Multiply it out for yourself!

Comment: @amd Question has been edited - I am still unable to see why we can switch the positions of the 1 and D given that the first two equations are not equivalent. Is there a particular reason why we don't need to be concerned about the switching of 1 and D?